# .htaccess does not load css and js

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess

I have 2 blog files one is `blogdetail.php` and `bloglist.php`. What i want to make is if someone enters on a link like this

```
http://mysite.com/blog
```

to open `bloglist.php` and when someone enters to

```
http://mysite.com/blog/7
```

to open `blogdetail.php?id=7`. My `.htaccess` so far looks like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ blogdetail.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

but the problem is when i enter on `blog/7`, the page opens but the css does not load. Is there a way to make this work without using absolute paths to css and js?
Thank you, Daniel!

Answer (score 1):

you are missing this rules in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ blogdetail.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Link your css file with `/` at beginning, and all will be fine.

Comment: i did that and now i dont see the css / js on the bloglist.php page eighter

Comment: could you give an url please?

Comment: dev.meghraj@ it is not absolute path, it is relative to document root