# .htaccess CSS is not getting loaded

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have coded a PHP website on `wamp` server, in that I have used `.htaccess` file to rewrite the URL.

My `.htaccess` is like,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test.*$ test.php?id=
```

It does rewriting the URL like `http://localhost/test/?id=5` to `http://localhost/test/5`

The issue is when I enter `http://localhost/test` it is loading the css correctly, but if I write `http://localhost/test/` the `css` is blocked.

I have checked the que : [.htaccess does not load css and js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801239/htaccess-does-not-load-css-and-js)

but I can not figure it out why this happening. where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test*$ test.php?id=
```

editted :

just remove `.`(dot) on `^test.*$`

Comment: just remove `.` on your `^test.*$`

Comment: Tried.. but still it is not loading the css, if I view the page source and when i click on css link it is not showing the source...

Comment: can you show the css path when using slash `user/` and just using `user` ?

Comment: I got the issue. it is because I have put a directory in my local host. after putting all the content in the www it is working cool!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

First, your code should look like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)$ /test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**MultiViews** is important here, because your symlink and file have the same base name.
This way, `http://localhost/test` won't be matched anymore (because this is not what you want). Neither `http://localhost/test/`, only `http://localhost/test/NUMBER` (without a trailing slash)

Then, your css (and images, and javascript, etc) problem is because of virtual directory generated by your rule. In other words, it is trying to resolve your css/images/js in `/test/` directory right now.

To avoid that behaviour, add this code in your file `test.php`, right after `<head>` html tag:
`<base href="http://localhost/" />`

Also, your css (and js, images, etc) html links must not begin with a slash `/`

Example for a css stylesheet:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />`
-----------------------------------------------^
No slash here

Comment: I want to approve this answer too!! but stack overflow is not allowing me.. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: You're welcome. But my answer provides you the solution when using virtual directories. You may want to use that, instead of avoiding it. That's up to you